# Class const to $variable

Tags: php, class, variables, constants

I have this code:

```
class ContactIntegration {

  const P_DESCRIPTION = 'description here';
  const MAIL_SENT_TRIGGER = '7_mail_sent';

  public $form_data;

  public $default_payload = array(

      'form_origem' => self::P_DESCRIPTION
  );
```

I need to change `const P_DESCRIPTION = 'description here';` to `const P_DESCRIPTION = $variable;` or `'form_origem' => self::P_DESCRIPTION` 
 to `'form_origem' => $variable;`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this is what you want.

```
class ContactIntegration {

  public static $variable= 'Any variable';
  const MAIL_SENT_TRIGGER = '7_mail_sent';

  public $form_data;

  public $default_payload = array(

      'form_origem' => self::$variable
  );
```

Comment: Fatihd, tks for reply.
But a error ocurred:
unexpected variable (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS)

Comment: Which php version do you use in server ?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.21.

But in fact I need to turn 'form_origem' => to a current page URL.

Also like this:
'form_origem' => "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a class constant or property's initial value to be the result of something dynamic (such as a variable or function result) in PHP. Instead, you should use a class method to set the property.

For example, this is **not** allowed:

```
<?php
$variable = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

class ContactIntegration {
    const P_DESCRIPTION = $variable;  // will cause an error

    public $default_payload = array(
        'form_origem' => $variable  // will also cause an error
    );
}
```

Instead, you should create an instance of your class and have your constructor (or some other function) set the variable:

```
<?php
$variable = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

class ContactIntegration {
    public $default_payload = array();

    function __construct($formOrigem) {
        $this->default_payload['form_origem'] = $formOrigem;
    }
}

$contactIntegration = new ContactIntegration($variable);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks Rick. This is the solution!